# Is it possible to set variable in pipeline?

Tags: bash, variables, pipeline

I have a big txt file which I want to edit in pipeline. But on same place in pipeline I want to set number of lines in variable $nol. I just want to see sintax how could I set variable in pipeline like:

```
  cat ${!#} | tr ' ' '\n'| grep . ; $nol=wc -l | sort | uniq -c ...
```

That after second pipe is very wrong, but how can I do it in bash?

One of solutions is:

```
nol=$(cat ${!#} | tr ' ' '\n'| grep . | wc -l)
pipeline all from the start again
```

but I don't want to do script the same thing twice, bec I have more pipes then here.

I musn't use awk or sed...

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? To me it looks like `awk` may be able to do it in one shot.

Comment: I musn't use awk or sed..

Comment: Still: maybe Bash alone can handle it. Try to give the big picture, because your questions are quite localized and might be hiding some conceptual problem. Also, it looks like storing the output up to a certain pipe in a variable can make it. Then, count lines and echo plus pipe to the rest of commands.

Comment: `| grep . ;` is this semicolon intentional?

Comment: I'm editing and sorting text file in pipeline. I just want to set number of lines in $nol somewhere in the middle of pipeline. I don't know how to explain in englis beter... I'm so sorry

Comment: yes, like new command it could be | too, just in that place I want to store number of lines in $nol, that's all

Comment: Marta, we still need more information in order to understand where you're going with this. Try to [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate where you're having trouble, and include a sample of your input, along with your intended output, in the question.

Comment: Also, am I interpreting this correctly -- you want `$nol` to be the number of distinct words in the last file specified on the command line?  Would `nol=$(wc -w < ${!#})` not do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `tee` and then write it to a file which you use later:

```
tempfile="xyz"
tr ' ' '\n' < "${!#}" | grep '.' | tee > "$tempfile" | sort | uniq -c ...
nol=$(wc -l "$tempfile")
```

Or you can use it the other way around:

```
nol=$(tr ' ' '\n' < "${!#}" | grep '.' \
  | tee >(sort | uniq -c ... > /dev/tty) | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable in a particular link of a pipeline, but that's not very useful since only that particular link will be affected by it.

I recommend simply using a temporary file.

```
set -e
trap 'rm -f "$tmpf"' EXIT
tmpf=`mktemp`
cat ${!#} | tr ' ' '\n'| grep . | sort > "$tmpf"
nol="$(wc "$tmpf")"
< "$tmpf" uniq -c ...
```

You can avoid the temporary file with tee and a named pipe, but it probably won't perform much better (it may even perform worse).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're asking how to avoid stepping through your file twice, just to get both word and line count.

Bash lets you read variables, and `wc` can produce all the numbers you need at once.

```
NAME
     wc -- word, line, character, and byte count
```

So to start...

```
read words line chars < <( wc < ${!#} )
```

This populates the three variables based on input generated from [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

But your question includes another partial command line which I think you intend as:

```
nol=$( sort -u ${!#} | wc -l )
```

This is markedly different from the word count of your first command line, so you can't use a single `wc` instance to generate both.  Instead, one option might be to put your functionality into a script that does both functions at once:

```
read words uniques < <(
awk '
      {
        words += NF
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { unique[$i] }
      }
      END {
        print words,length(unique)
      }
    ' ${!#}
)
```

Comment: `${#!}` did you mean this ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Took a minute but I got it...

```
cat ${!#} | tr ' ' '\n'| tee >(nol=$(wc -l)) | sort | uniq -c ...
```

**PREVIOUS:**

The only way I can think to do this is storing in variables and calling back.  You would not execute the command more than one time.  You would just store the output in variables along the way.

```
aCommand=($(cat ${!#} | tr ' ' '\n'));sLineCount=$(echo ${#aCommand[@]});echo ${aCommand[@]} | sort | uniq -c ...
```

- aCommand will store the results of the first set of commands in an array
- sLineCount will count the elements (lines) in the array
- ;... echo the array elements and continue the commands from there.